# JavaMail - FetchProfile.Item.CONTENT_INFO breaks .getContent()

Tags: java, email, imap, jakarta-mail

If I add `FetchProfile.Item.CONTENT_INFO` to the FetchProfile a `javax.mail.Folder`, `.getContent()` and `.getInputStream()` only returns empty strings, as if the content is not fetched at all. If I don't set the `CONTENT_INFO` flag, the content is fetched just fine.

However it only happens if the message is `text/plain; charset:us-ascii`. If it's `multipart` or `text/html`, it works fine.

Can anyone tell me why this happens?